# creating a c++ project in visual studio

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a c++ project in visual basic but when I first create the project, the main.cpp file [the .cpp file which contains the main function] has the following comment

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

and when i remove it, i get the following errors:

Error (active)  E2849   PCH warning: cannot find a suitable header stop location.  An IntelliSense PCH file was not generated.
Error   C2857   '#include' statement specified with the /Ycstdafx.h command-line option was not found in the source file

how can I get rid of those errors?

Comment: Do you mean [VIsual *Studio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)? Because [Visual Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) is a *language*, a variant of [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC).

Comment: As for your problem, *don't* remove the `#include "stdafx.h"`?

Comment: _"..has the following comment"_: that's your problem; this `#include "stdafx.h"` is __not__ a comment.  You to read a beginners book on C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove precompiled headers options with the file, you can do that using these instructions from Microsoft->https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1010